# Renaming parts of a file name using regex and powershell

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

I have some files that I would like to rename using regex and powershell, but I am not sure of the patterns for the files.

Example of file names I need to rename and what they should end up looking like. ps placing the names in “” to account for spaces.

**How the files are named now**

“[abs] anima.some e147 name [480p].avi” 
“anima.some e147 name #anim group .avi” 
“anima.some e147 name [480p].avi” 
“anima some e147 name [480p].avi”

**How they should be name**

“Anime some e147.avi”

Comment: Powershell actually isn't capable of handling filenames with `[]` in them, so you will need to do more than just renaming and regex, like use some .NET classes.

Comment: Thanks for the info ,if you can make this work using .NET in Powershell that would be an acceptable solution to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
# Create array of filenames
$files = 
"[abs] anima.some e147 name [480p].avi",
"anima.some e147 name #anim group .avi",
"anima.some e147 name [480p].avi",
"anima some e147 name [480p].avi"

# Setup patterns to match against
$pattern1 = "\[\w+\] ([^.]+).([\w]+) ([\S]+) [\w]+ \[[\w]+\].avi"
$pattern2 = "([^.\s]+).([\w]+) ([\S]+) .*.avi"

# Loop through file names and attempt matching
foreach($f in $files)
{
    if($f -match $pattern1)
    {
        $string = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($matches[1]) + " " + $matches[2] + " " + $matches[3] + ".avi"
        $string
    }
    elseif($f -match $pattern2)
    {
        $string = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($matches[1]) + " " + $matches[2] + " " + $matches[3] + ".avi"
        $string
    }
    else
    {
        "unmatched file: " + $f
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Anima some e147.avi
Anima some e147.avi
Anima some e147.avi
Anima some e147.avi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked 100% for what i wanted slotted it in to m code and it is working now, i bought a book on regex now so will be learning that. Just a question I have never used the Get-Culture what does it actually do , I checked powershell help and it did not really explain it.

Comment: Get-Culture return a System.Globalization.CultureInfo object. That object has a TextInfo property that exposes the "ToTitleCase()" method. That method is just a convenient tool to take a string like "rAmdoN cAse" and change it to "Random Case".